# How to make Ctrl+F show only the partitions in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. In 14.04 when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the Dash only showed the partitions available to the system, and I could easily go through them and select the one I wanted to open. This feature was very convenient for me. But in 16.04, it shows some other folders as well (see the below picture). I don't remember what I did back then (almost 2 years ago) to set it as I wanted. It came with the package, but I definitely want it back.

In the below picture, I don't want the folders in the red rectangle to appear when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

#### Question:

How can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> list only the partitions?

Comment: Probably ain't possible without modifying and recompiling Unity source code itself.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but you can open Files, go to `computer:///`, and it will show you all accessible partitions. You could make a keyboard shortcut that opens it.